# How to verify the password in MongoDB and php?

Tags: php, mongodb, authentication

I am working on page with register and login possibilities.
It always says that the password is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?
I also tried with iterator_to_array, it doesn't work either.

```
$db = get_db();

                $mojlogin = $_POST['login'];
                $mojehaslo = $_POST['haslo'];
                empty($mors);
                $mors = $db->morsy->findOne(array('login' => $mojlogin, "haslo1" => $mojehaslo));


                if(password_verify($mojehaslo, $mors['haslo1'])){

                    echo "Zalogowany!\n";
                    $powitanie = "Witaj ponownie, ".$mojlogin."!";

                    echo "<h1 class='tytul'>$powitanie</h1>";
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $mojlogin;
                } else {
                    echo "Niepoprawny login lub hasło!\n";


                }
```

Comment: What is the definition of `password_verify` method?

Comment: Do you mean something like "it checks if password matches the hash"?
I haven't slept in 22h, please be gentle.

Comment: Sorry, I am not being harsh. I just wanted to see the code of `password_verify` method.

Comment: @dikesh It is a default PHP function. You can take a look at documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: @Weronica I have updated my answer with the code. Feel free to clarify any obscurities.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from your code, you request the user password and use it as a search criteria to get his account from the database, which implies that instead of storing the **hash** of the password, you store the **password** itself.

The proper way to do this is to generate hash first, store it in `haslo1` field, and then use it as a second argument in the `password_verify` function along with the actual password in `$mojehaslo` as the first one. Furthermore, you only use `$mojlogin` in the `findOne()` query, because the idea is to get the hash from the database corresponding to user login and compare it to the password that was entered.

You normally want to generate your hash using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Then, after you place it in `haslo1` document field, you use almost the same code as you did before:

```
$mors = $db->morsy->findOne([ 'login' => $mojlogin ]);
if (password_verify($mojehaslo, $mors['haslo1'])) {
    // here goes your entrance code
}
```

Comment: I store hash, I checked this. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check var_dump, always.

After not getting my login, my friends told me to use:

```
var_dump(iterator_to_array($db->morsy->find()))
```

I had white space before login, because of mistakes in form.

Comment: Yes, it is. :) Login code was fine - although not version from here, my first one.